# Aggregate by NA in R

Tags: r, aggregate, na

Does anybody know how to aggregate by NA in R.

If you take the example below

```
a <- matrix(1,5,2)
a[1:2,2] <- NA
a[3:5,2] <- 2
aggregate(a[,1], by=list(a[,2]), sum)
```

The output is:

```
Group.1 x
2       3
```

But is there a way to get the output to include NAs in the output like this:

```
Group.1 x
2       3
NA      2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `aggregate()`, you may want to consider `rowsum()`.  It is actually designed for this exact operation on matrices and is known to be much faster than `aggregate()`.  We can add `NA` to the factor levels of `a[, 2]` with `addNA()`.  This will assure that `NA` shows up as a grouping variable.

```
rowsum(a[, 1], addNA(a[, 2]))
#      [,1]
# 2       3
# <NA>    2
```

If you still want to use `aggregate()`, you can incorporate `addNA()` as well.

```
aggregate(a[, 1], list(Group = addNA(a[, 2])), sum)
#   Group x
# 1     2 3
# 2  <NA> 2
```

And one more option with *data.table* -

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(a)[, .(x = sum(V1)), by = .(Group = V2)]
#    Group x
# 1:    NA 2
# 2:     2 3
```

Comment: finally the proper `data.table` alternative

Comment: Thank you Richard, your second option is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use summarize from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(V2) %>%
  summarize(V1_sum = sum(V1))
```

Answer (score 3):

> Using `sqldf`:

```
a <- as.data.frame(a)
sqldf("SELECT V2 [Group], SUM(V1) x 
      FROM a 
      GROUP BY V2")
```

Output:

```
  Group x
1    NA 2
2     2 3
```

> stats package

A variation of AdamO's proposal:

```
data.frame(xtabs( V1 ~ V2 , data = a,na.action = na.pass, exclude = NULL))
```

Output:

```
    V2 Freq
1    2    3
2 <NA>    2
```

Comment: The base option is not a solution. The OP asked for a sum, it is just a coincidence that the *count* is the *sum* (because the summand column is all ones). Try `a[, 1] <- 1:5` for an example of why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi AdamO, thank you for pointing that out. I offered an alternative solution and when I posted i realized that it was basically your proposal, with a slightly different syntax. I leave it as a reference noting is a variation of your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `addNA` solution of Rich doesn't require any substantial change to the `aggregate` syntax, so I think it's the best solution. I'll point out that another option, which produces output similar to `table` (and thus can be coerced into a `data.frame` structure similar to that of `aggregate`) is `xtabs`.

```
xtabs(a[, 1] ~ a[, 2], addNA=T)
```

Gives:

```
  Group.1 x
1       2 3
2    <NA> 2
```

Another "trick" I see is assigning a missing code to these data. We all like the `NA` output of R, but assigning a missing code to a grouping variable is a good coding exercise. We take it so that it has one more digit than the largest value in the dataset and is of the form -999...99.

`codemiss <- function(x) -10^(floor(log(max(abs(x), na.rm=T), base=10))+2)-1`

works in general.

Then you get

`a[, 2][is.na(a[, 2])] <- codemiss(a[, 2])`

And:

`aggregate(a[, 1], list(a[, 2]), sum)`

Gives you:

```
  Group.1 x
1     -99 2
2       2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try aggregating by `is.na(a[,2])` instead.

```
aggregate(a[,1], by=list(is.na(a[,2])), sum)

#   Group.1 x
# 1   FALSE 3
# 2    TRUE 2
```

If you want a finer distinction than just `NA` or not, then you may want to define a new variable that uses an previously unused value to denote `NA` (a factor would be more elegant, but a numeric vector is the simplest):

```
b <- a[,2]
b[is.na(b)] <- 999
aggregate(a[,1], by=list(b), sum)

#   Group.1 x
# 1       2 3
# 2     999 2
```